# Fog does not obscure horizon in Unity

Tags: unity, fog

If you look through fog that continues to horizon it should obscure the horizon. But in Unity (so far) it seems that the horizon shows clearly through the fog. This ruins my underwater effects, etc.

Is there a way to get the horizon to obscure behind the fog?

It is worth noting that I am speaking of fog in conjunction with a procedural skybox.

EDIT, per request:

See this image -- this fog settings at .1 (extreme, for this example, official "thick-as-pea-soup" fog. This is using the lighting-settings fog. Frustratingly enough, the global fog camera effect only destroy/bugs my scene, so I'm stuck using this.

I'm using default procedural skybox (I intend to do day/night effects with it)

It fades out the railing nicely, but the horizon is shown as though there is no fog. The horizon should be fog color.[image]

Comment: A picture would be worth a thousand words here. Showing us the rendered appearance of your scene, you fog settings, and your skybox settings would be ideal. Otherwise we have to speculate about how you've set things up and may give you advice that's not relevant for your specific needs.